# How to assign unique id to each select box for the following scenario

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used below code to develop dynamic select box which has Unique id's.i.e In single click i am generating two select boxes.

```
$(function () {
    var nextRowID = 0;
    var nextRowID1 = 1;
        $("body").on("click", "#btnAdd", function () {
    var id = ++nextRowID;
    var id1 = ++nextRowID1; 
            var partipiansRow = '<div><select class="drop_dwn_mult" id="name' + id + '"><option>Sample1</option><option>Sample2</option><option>Sample3</option><option>Sample4</option></select><select class="drop_dwn_mult" id="name' + id1 + '"><option>Sample1</option><option>Sample2</option><option>Sample3</option><option>Sample4</option></select>' +
            '<i class="fa fa-minus-square remove" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true" id="btnAdd"></i></div>';
    $('#TextBoxContainer').append(partipiansRow);   


});
```

But the ouput i am getting as below as

```
    <div id="TextBoxContainer">
                        <!--Textboxes will be added here -->
   <div><select class="drop_dwn_mult" id="name1"><option>Sample1</option><option>Sample2</option><option>Sample3</option><option>Sample4</option></select><select class="drop_dwn_mult" id="name2"><option>Sample1</option><option>Sample2</option><option>Sample3</option><option>Sample4</option></select><i class="fa fa-minus-square remove" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true" id="btnAdd"></i></div>
<div><select class="drop_dwn_mult" id="name2"><option>Sample1</option><option>Sample2</option><option>Sample3</option><option>Sample4</option></select><select class="drop_dwn_mult" id="name3"><option>Sample1</option><option>Sample2</option><option>Sample3</option><option>Sample4</option></select><i class="fa fa-minus-square remove" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true" id="btnAdd"></i></div></div>
```

In the above HTML totally i have four select boxes in which i cant able to generate unique ID's.

Please help me to generate unique id's for all select boxes.

Comment: use https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random ?

Comment: What's the purpose of the id?

Comment: If i click for First select box it will get data and populate to other one. Likewise it will do for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `id1` is always simply 1 greater than `id`, you could increment `nextRowID` as you define `id` & `id1`. It will simplify your counter (`nextRowID`) while avoiding the condition where the previous `nextRowID` and current `nextRowID1` are the same number.

```js
var nextRowID = 0;
//var nextRowID1 = 1;
$("body").on("click", "#btnAdd", function() {
  var id = ++nextRowID;
  var id1 = ++nextRowID;
  var partipiansRow = '<div>[id = name'+ id +'] <select class="drop_dwn_mult" id="name' + id + '"><option>Sample1</option><option>Sample2</option><option>Sample3</option><option>Sample4</option></select><br />[id = name'+ id1 +']<select class="drop_dwn_mult" id="name' + id1 + '"><option>Sample1</option><option>Sample2</option><option>Sample3</option><option>Sample4</option></select>' +
    '<i class="fa fa-minus-square remove" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true" id="btnAdd"></i></div>';
  $('#TextBoxContainer').append(partipiansRow);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnAdd">Add</button>
<div id="TextBoxContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
$("body").on("click", ".btnAdd", function() {
  var id = $('.drop_dwn_mult').length+1;
  var id1 = $('.drop_dwn_mult').length+2;
  var partipiansRow = '<div><select class="drop_dwn_mult" id="name' + id + '"><option>Sample1</option><option>Sample2</option><option>Sample3</option><option>Sample4</option></select><select class="drop_dwn_mult" id="name' + id1 + '"><option>Sample1</option><option>Sample2</option><option>Sample3</option><option>Sample4</option></select>' +
    '<button class=btnAdd>Add</button></div>';
  $('#TextBoxContainer').append(partipiansRow);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='btnAdd'>Add</button>
<div id='TextBoxContainer'></div>
```

Another suggestion is that I can see you have added a dynamic add button in the string template and you have assigned an id of `btnAdd` which can cause you in an invalid markup because IDs should be unique for each element so click event only will be happen for first button.

Solution to this issue is to change to class names instead, as in the answer above.

<sub>*For the example i have changed the add button.*</sub>